# Which app will help me remove limitations on DVDs?

Tags: dvd

I purchased an exercise DVD that was created by a local health practitioner. Whoever created the DVD for her used some wonky settings that prevent me from being able to go into fast-forward mode on my DVD player. The DVD is not copy-protected.

Is there a Mac program that I can get that will let me make a copy of the DVD but without silly settings such as "no fast forwarding"?

Comment: This company is well respected and have been doing good software for years. http://thelittleappfactory.com/ripit/ Give the demo a try and let us know how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found [MacDVDRipperPro](http://www.macdvdripperpro.com/) to work very well for me. It also removes the protection on dvd's.

Answer (score 1):

You mean a DVD protection remover? I believe many tools have been designed for this purchase so far. From my opinion, I prefer dvdaid since it has successully copied all my DVD collection. No need for the original disc anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Try [MakeMKV](http://www.makemkv.com), I use it to rip DVDs and Blu Rays to a single MKV file.

I then use [Handbrake](https://www.handbrake.fr) to rip the MKV to an MP4 file.

I then use [MetaZ](http://griff.github.io/metaz/) to tag the files appropriately.  This includes cover art, year, genre, description, etc.  If you're watching your content on an AppleTV, these are the only tags you need to worry about.

As they're MP4 files, they drag and drop right into iTunes and play on my AppleTV.